# Digraph transition labels far from arrows

Tags: graphviz, digraphs

Some transition labels from my graph are far from the transition arrow.
(see picutre and source code)

How can I fix this ?

```
digraph summary {
nodesep=1.0
graph [splines=ortho, nodesep=3.0]
node [height=2, width=3, fixedsize=true]

front_office [label="dématia front office",shape=box, style=filled, fillcolor=lightblue]

autorise [label="autorisé:\n- campagne ouvert + délai\l- login succès\l- diplômé authorisé (IS ou prog)",shape=diamond, style=filled, fillcolor=lightyellow]
premiere_connexion [label="première connexion\n(pas de dossier dematia actif)",shape=diamond, style=filled, fillcolor=lightyellow]
origine [label="origine",shape=diamond, style=filled, fillcolor=lightyellow]
rejet [label="rejet",shape=box, style=filled, fillcolor=lightblue]
creation_pre [nojustify=true label="création pré:\n-étudiant\l-individu\l-historique\l-inscription\l...",shape=box, style=filled, fillcolor=lightblue]

front_office->autorise
autorise->premiere_connexion [label="OUI"]
autorise->rejet [label="NON"]
origine->creation_pre[label="①précandidat éxiste\n(candidat parcoursup)"]
origine->creation_pre[label="②progression éxiste\n(candidat unc)"]
premiere_connexion->origine [label="OUI"]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dot` gave this error

> Warning: Orthogonal edges do not currently handle edge labels. Try
> using xlabels.

Changing *most of* the edge labels to xlabels:

```
digraph summary {
nodesep=1.0
graph [splines=ortho, nodesep=3.0]
node [height=2, width=3, fixedsize=true]

front_office [label="dématia front office",shape=box, style=filled, fillcolor=lightblue]

autorise [label="autorisé:\n- campagne ouvert + délai\l- login succès\l- diplômé authorisé (IS ou prog)",shape=diamond, style=filled, fillcolor=lightyellow]
premiere_connexion [label="première connexion\n(pas de dossier dematia actif)",shape=diamond, style=filled, fillcolor=lightyellow]
origine [label="origine",shape=diamond, style=filled, fillcolor=lightyellow]
rejet [label="rejet",shape=box, style=filled, fillcolor=lightblue]
creation_pre [nojustify=true label="création pré:\n-étudiant\l-individu\l-historique\l-inscription\l...",shape=box, style=filled, fillcolor=lightblue]
 
front_office->autorise
autorise->premiere_connexion [xlabel="OUI"]
autorise->rejet [xlabel="NON"]
origine->creation_pre[label="précandidat éxiste\n(candidat parcoursup)"]
origine->creation_pre[xlabel="progression éxiste\n(candidat unc)"]
premiere_connexion->origine [xlabel="OUI"]
}
```

Gives:
[image]